# RewriteCond pattern group not matching

Tags: .htaccess

Firstly, I have followed a lot of links around trying to figure this out for myself, but I can't seem to get it to work for me.

I am using codeigniter as a framework and htaccess is all great and working well, but my client wants to let verification files be picked up on their system (google verification stuff). The files are named something like google1234324324232.html

This is what I have currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|css|js|sitemap*|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

So I foolishly thought this would work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|css|js|sitemap*|robots\.txt|*.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But that actually gives me a 500 error, and I guess it's something to do with the wildcard, and I have tried regex pattern matching, but it always seems to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` doesn't work like that. It must follow a character which you want to match 0 or more of. Likewise, `sitemap*` is probably not doing what you think it does. `sitemap*` will match any of the following:

```
sitema
sitemap
sitemapppppppppp
```

because the `*` applies to the `p`. For `*.html`, the `*` has no character to apply to, thus a regex error. You want:

```
.*\.html
```

The `.` character means "anything".